# Cerrar sesion en c# con javascrip

Tags: javascript, c#

Hola amigos gusto en saludarlos, bueno tengo un problema, estoy haciendo el cerrar sesión en c# mvc, ya tengo mi cerrar sesión funciona normal, pero ahora quiero llamar la función  desde un JavaScript. Les muestro el código c# que funciona normal.

```
       <div class="widget-content-right mr-2">
 @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
 {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<button class="btn-pill btn-shadow btn-shine btn btn-focus">
 Logout
 </button>
</div>
```

pero ahora quiero llamarlo en la siguiente función JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 6; //seconds
    var _idleSecondsCounter = 0;

    document.onclick = function () {
        _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
    };

    document.onmousemove = function () {
        _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
    };

    document.onkeypress = function () {
        _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
    };

    window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, 1000);

    function CheckIdleTime() {
        _idleSecondsCounter++;
        var oPanel = document.getElementById("SecondsUntilExpire");
        if (oPanel)
            oPanel.innerHTML = (IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter) + "";
        if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
            alert("Time expired!");
            Session.Abandon();

-------- AQUI LO QUIERO LLAMAR------

            document.location.href = "prueba.html";
        }
    }
</script>
```

por favor si hay alguien que me ayude le agradecería mucho.

Comment: El primer código está presente en la página??

Comment: si esta presente

Answer (score 0):

Una opción sería crear una variable con la ruta de ese LogOff y se la pasa a window.location, asi:

```
var redireccionarLogin = "@Url.Action("LogOff", "Account")";
window.location = redireccionarLogin;
```

O simplemente trata de pasarle la ruta directamente al window.location, y listo, en teoría debería redireccionar a ese LogOff.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más simple es generar el submit del logout haciendo `logoutForm.submit();`

```
function CheckIdleTime() {
        _idleSecondsCounter++;
        var oPanel = document.getElementById("SecondsUntilExpire");
        if (oPanel)
            oPanel.innerHTML = (IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter) + "";
        if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
            alert("Time expired!");
            Session.Abandon();

-------- AQUI LO QUIERO LLAMAR------

           logoutForm.submit();
        }
    }
```

Por otro lado te recomiendo subir el tiempo de intervalo, 1s me parece demasiado para comprobar el estado de la session, 1 minuto aprox creo que estaría mejor.